# Stacking buttons in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I want to stack multiple (circular) buttons in Android. This is what I want to achieve: http://imageshack.us/photo/photo/19/0gp1.jpg/

I tried to put multiple buttons inside a single RelativeLayout (and set their position to absolute positions) but that didn't gave the result I wanted to achieve, because the buttons didn't have the correct position on different densities/screen sizes. Does anyone have experience with this kind of buttons/layouts? What can I do to achieve this result?

Comment: You can create such drawables and place a button over top of another

Comment: u need to work with ImageButton

Comment: I know but the buttons will still be a square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it in a RelativeView, First build btn1, then btn2, and then on the another RelativeLayout btn3 and btn4, and finally btn 5 and give then background image. All you should do is to take care of their sizes.

EDIT  :

here is a code I wrote no :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:text="btn1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"
            android:text="btn2" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:text="btn3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn3"
                android:text="btn4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn5"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="btn5" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, but when i do this are the touchzones then also round?

Comment: try it , it should be fine if you add background image to them

Comment: no problem mate :) if it's fine and working would you please accept it as a correct answer ?

Comment: Hahaha yes of course! :)

Answer (score 0):

For creating this type of `buttons` you have to cut the `Image` into different sizes and put it inside a `ImagesButton` in `Layout` and use it very simple.